# Amazon AWS Elastic Beanstalk service is down

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am not able to access Amazon Aws Elastic Beanstalk page. I am getting below error page [image: Elastic Beansstalk is down]

I am also not able to deploy any code to Elastic BeanStalk.

Comment: I have the same too. Must be a problem on AWS --- Why are you posting this here? What's your question?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not even a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a service outage at the time. It should work for you now.

See: [AWS Service Health Dashboard](http://status.aws.amazon.com/)